# DAX measure that only displays values for a specific column in a Power Pivot table

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot, dax, powerpivot

The newest DAX functions like ISINSCOPE are still limited to Excel Insiders, so I only have access to the ones up to Excel 2019.

I have two tables in a one-to-many relationship on the 'area' column:

[Example tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dofKt.jpg)

I would like the measure to return values for the data in the 'area'  column only of the 'one' table, with all other categories/subcategories being blank. For instance, a COUNT measure of the 'area' column in the 'many' table produces the following results in differently ordered pivot tables:

[Standard COUNT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKZX8.jpg)

What DAX code is required to make it look like this in both? This is needed in case the user rearranges the order of the row labels:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbkjH.jpg)

I've tried varying combinations of ISFILTERED, HASONEFILTER, HASONEVALUE, but can't find a solution that works properly in both layouts of the pivot tables. There is probably a completely different approach to this, but I'm still new to DAX.

Comment: Could you create a new measure like: `ScopeTest:=ISINSCOPE(Names[area])` and try it in your pivot. There are some function that show with red underline, but still work.